# Decrease size of converted audio file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio

I am converting my recorded audio which is in .m4a format to .caf format. The settings of the recorded audio is as given below:

```
/* Record settings for recording the audio*/ 
recordSetting = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],AVFormatIDKey,
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                 nil];
```

I convert the audio to .caf using this function:

```
-(NSString *)handleConvertToPCM:(NSURL *)convertUrl 
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showActivity) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    DEBUG_LOG(@"DEBUGGING");
    DEBUG_LOG(@"handleConvertToPCM");
    // open an ExtAudioFile
    NSLog (@"opening %@", convertUrl);
    ExtAudioFileRef inputFile;
    CheckResult (ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)convertUrl, &inputFile),
                 "ExtAudioFileOpenURL failed");
    // prepare to convert to a plain ol' PCM format
    AudioStreamBasicDescription requiredPCMFormat;
    requiredPCMFormat.mSampleRate = 44100; // todo: or use source rate?
    requiredPCMFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM ;
    requiredPCMFormat.mFormatFlags =  kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;   
    requiredPCMFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    requiredPCMFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    requiredPCMFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    requiredPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    requiredPCMFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
    CheckResult (ExtAudioFileSetProperty(inputFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                         sizeof (requiredPCMFormat), &requiredPCMFormat),
                 "ExtAudioFileSetProperty failed");
    // allocate a big buffer. size can be arbitrary for ExtAudioFile.
    UInt32 outputBufferSize = 0x10000;
    void* ioBuf = malloc (outputBufferSize);
    UInt32 sizePerPacket = requiredPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket;   
    UInt32 packetsPerBuffer = outputBufferSize / sizePerPacket;
    // set up output file   
    self.outputPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/export-pcm.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
    self.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.outputPath];
    DEBUG_LOG(@"creating output file %@", self.outputURL);
    AudioFileID outputFile;
    CheckResult(AudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)outputURL,
                                       kAudioFileCAFType,
                                       &requiredPCMFormat, 
                                       kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, 
                                       &outputFile),
                "AudioFileCreateWithURL failed");
    // start convertin'
    UInt32 outputFilePacketPosition = 0; //in bytes
    while (true) 
    {
        // wrap the destination buffer in an AudioBufferList
        AudioBufferList convertedData;
        convertedData.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        convertedData.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = requiredPCMFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        convertedData.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = outputBufferSize;
        convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData = ioBuf;
        UInt32 frameCount = packetsPerBuffer;
        // read from the extaudiofile
        CheckResult (ExtAudioFileRead(inputFile,
                                      &frameCount,
                                      &convertedData),
                     "Couldn't read from input file");
        if (frameCount == 0) 
        {
            printf ("done reading from file");
            break;
        }
        // write the converted data to the output file
        CheckResult (AudioFileWritePackets(outputFile,
                                           false,
                                           frameCount,
                                           NULL,
                                           outputFilePacketPosition / requiredPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket, 
                                           &frameCount,
                                           convertedData.mBuffers[0].mData),
                     "Couldn't write packets to file");

        DEBUG_LOG(@"Converted %ld bytes", outputFilePacketPosition);
        // advance the output file write location
        outputFilePacketPosition += (frameCount * requiredPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket);
    }
    // clean up
    ExtAudioFileDispose(inputFile);
    AudioFileClose(outputFile);
    return(self.outputPath);    

}
```

My problem is that the size of the converted file is very high compared to the file given for conversion.Is there anyway to decrease the size by changing the conversion settings.
I tried compressing the file obtained , but it takes much time to compress.So I would like to get a way to decrease size along with conversion.

Comment: You are decoding an MP4 file into plain PCM. That certainly results into a huge size increase. Why are you converting the file in the first place?

Comment: Its required like that.Any way to decrease the size.Will any change in settings work?I tried some but failed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with writing music in iOs, but when converting sounds with a tool for my game going to mono from stereo decreased the size by half. Maybe mono is sufficient for you?

Comment: You may end up with smaller files by: reducing the two channels (aka stereo) to one channel, reducing the encoder bitrate (e.g. 32kbps), reducing the playback rate (e.g 22kHz). In any case, do not use PCM but stick with AAC encoding (MP4 files).

Comment: It's not working if I change any of the settings.The application will crash and the error says Error: ExtAudioFileSetProperty failed ('fmt?') which occurs during CheckResult (ExtAudioFileSetProperty()).

Comment: Only changing the sampling rate worked.A present I use 12000 instead of 44100.It helped to decrease the size to an extend.

Answer (score 0):

Decompressing a highly compressed audio file almost always results in a much larger result file, unless you re-compress using an even lossier compression format.

Comment: Is there any way to recompress the audio which is less time consuming?

Comment: For caf format, file size will be proportional to the sample rate (commonly 44.1kHz) times the bits per sample (commonly 16 bits or 2 bytes) times the number of channels (1, 2 or 5), times the length of the audio in seconds.  Which do you want to reduce?

Comment: The size of my 2 minute audio after conversion is nearly 20MB.I would like to reduce it to a maximum size of 5MB.What settings should I use to achieve this?

Comment: Halve 2 of the 4 things.  Any 2.

Comment: It's not working if I change any of the settings.The application will crash and the error says Error: ExtAudioFileSetProperty failed ('fmt?') which occurs during CheckResult (ExtAudioFileSetProperty()).

Comment: Only changing the sampling rate worked.A present I use 12000 instead of 44100.It helped to decrease the size to an extend.